# UIView backgroundColor still white, after changing to clear

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

In my app I have a ViewController with 2 separated UIViews, but they both have the same frame and positions. Their background color is clear. I take screenshot of each of them and after look at pixel data of each UIImage. When I take screenshot of second UIView, I change backgrond color of UIView to white, because otherwise they overlap each other. At this moment all work correct, after I return background color to clear.

But when I try to repeat call my function again, first UIView has white pixels inside, like previous UIView still doesn't change background color.

I'm changing background color with:

```
secondView.backgroundColor = nil // also with = .clear
```

Here is my method to take screenshot:

```
func takeScreenshot(_ targetUIView: UIView,completion: @escaping(_ image: UIImage) ->Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetUIView.bounds.size, targetUIView.isOpaque, UIScreen.main.scale)
        targetUIView.drawHierarchy(in: targetUIView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                if (image != nil){
                    completion(image!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I tried:

- Tried to hide view, where I change background color.
- Tried to remove it from superview.
- Tried to use setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout methods.
- Tried to change view in hierarchy with bringSubviewToFront and sendSubviewToBack methods.

All of this was useless for me, somehow it look like my second UIView still has white background color, even I change it to clear.

Comment: try to send opaque value false

Comment: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetUIView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)`

Comment: it is false) Sorry forget to write it. Still have this issue. Actually i tried to play it with opque and not